# Sybase ASE - List table names, column names, constraint names in a DB

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

Can I get a query to list out parent and child table names, parent and child column names, constraints, and constraint types in a Sybase ASE DB?

Comment: I assume you haven't looked at the underlying SQL code in sp_help, sp_helpconstraint etc - this will do what you need. You can run sp_helptext 'sp_help' in sybsystemprocs for example to get the SQL.

Comment: @RichCampbell, I am unable to get the source code of sp_help as I am blocked from accessing it. Is there an alternate to get it?

Comment: Ask your DBA to extract it for you they will have access to run the sp_helptext without any issues.